# Getting an error 'Couldn't rename temporary file' while using an ant statement replaceregexp

Tags: regex, ant, build-script

In the build script there's a 'replaceregexp' statement which is resulting in the error 'Couldn't rename temporary file C:\Users\CH~1\AppData\Local\Tempo\replace945396414885390382.txt'

I'm doing build on a packaged solution from IBM.
Using java 1.8.0_111, ant 1.7.1

```
<replaceregexp file="${runtime}/properties/filename.cfg" match="VENDOR_JAR=(.*)[\\/]*jar[\\/]*ant[\\/]*(.*)" replace="#VENDOR_JAR=\1jar/ant/\2" byline="true" />
```

There are 4 entries which match the above regex expression and 3 out of the 4 is commented as mentioned in the statement.

Comment: `There are 4 entries which match the above regex expression and 3 out of the 4 is commented as mentioned in the statement`.  Don't see any regex nor a statement that shows anything.

Comment: Apologies, not sure how it got missed. Here is the ant statement,<replaceregexp file="${runtime}/properties/dynamicclasspath_working.cfg" match="VENDOR_JAR=(.*)[\\/]*jar[\\/]*ant[\\/]*(.*)" replace="#VENDOR_JAR=\1jar/ant/\2" byline="true" />